# MS Access database not up to date? (VS Web Developer Studio)

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, web

I'm taking a class in C# web dev and I'm currently trying to display data from a `.mdb` (Microsoft Access) database. I have two pages that both want to show a table stored in the database in a grid view. One page's form uses function that connects the the db and then writes to the table to the grid. it connects with this call:

```
sqlConn = new OleDbConnection("PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
        "Data Source=" + Database);


sqlDA = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from tblPersonnel where LastName = '"+strSearch+"'", sqlConn);

//Initialize a new activity 
DS = new dsPersonnel();

//Add rows to the dataset from the data source
sqlDA.Fill(DS.tblPersonnel);
```

The database is called `PayrollSystem_DB.mdb`. In the other page I placed a `SqlDataSource` control on the page and connected it to `PayrollSystem_DB.mdb`. Then set this to the `gridView`. However when running, the the first page shows a long table with data I've entered since last week. and the 2nd page shows only data from the first day I tested it. Looking at the db in the vs explorer the tables are identical to teh second page.

So I'm wondering were all the other data is being stored that the first page is showing? Am I unknowingly using a database I can't see in the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but have you tried clearing your browsers cache and then looking at the first page again? Try that. If the data is still showing I would compare the size of the MDB before and after an insert to see if the MDB grows. If not, try a search of all the files on your PC limiting it to only files modified recently, I think that will at least help you find where the data is being stored.